# Mapping Object Array Data in Redux

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, mapping, redux

I'm using axios and redux for an api request that returns a response.data which is an array of objects.

My action reducer is as follows:

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
     case FETCH_USERS:
         console.log(action.payload.data)
         return { ...state, users: action.payload.data };
       }
  return state;
}
```

The console.log returns this in the chrome console

```
 [object, object]
```

My problem arises to how I can map the data of objects. I tried the following where I mapped the array. (Users is the prop of the object array.)

```
  ....
 {this.props.users.map(this.renderUser)}
 ...

 renderUser(user) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td> {user.contact_name}</td>
      <td> {user.contact_email}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

When I use the React console to check my props i get the following:

```
users: {...}
   users: 
      0:{...}
      1:{...}
```

I'm not sure how to map the objects to html. Would it be better if I converted it to string and mapped that? My mapping appears blank.

Comment: You didn't say it but what's your problem? your mapping doesn't work?

Comment: @QoP sorry, I edited my post. My mapping does not work and appears blank.

Comment: how are you mapping your redux state to your component?

Comment: function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { users: state.users };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Users);    

I'm using the React plugin and the props seem to be present so I think it might be a mapping issue

Comment: check the answer :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your state has the same name as your array and that is confusing you.

Your users reducer is

```
const initialState = {
   ....
   users : []
}
```

when you map it to your props using the name "users" what you got is

```
this.props.users = initialState
```

so in order to access to users you need to use

```
this.props.users.users
```

That said, the way to access to your users is like this.

```
  ....
 {this.props.users.users.map(this.renderUser)}
 ...

 renderUser(user) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td> {user.contact_name}</td>
      <td> {user.contact_email}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, however when I do this.props.users.users.map I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined. There's probably something else that's causing this issue but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: do you have an initial state?

Comment: Would the export default function(state = [], action)  from the reducer be the initial state?

Comment: yeah but that doesn't contain users, state = { users : []} would be a better idea. You are probably accessing to your users.users before fetching the data and users doesnt exist, thats why you got that error

Comment: seems like there's a better underlying mapping fix. I'm not sure what it is though. I've got the same thing going on and instead of checking if `this.props.users.users` exist I'd rather just be able to always rely `this.props.users`

Comment: @MichaelR see my answer below on how to make that fix.

Answer (score 1):

In `store`, if your `users` is  a nested object, you can fix this in `mapStateToProps`.
It not only tells react/redux *which* data you want but also,
how to transform/map said data from the way it is stored in the redux `store`,
to how you'd like it to appear on `props`:

```
mapStateToProps( store ){
  return {
    users: store.users.users,
  }
}
```

Now, within your component, you can access and map over your `users` (array) as `this.props.users`, rather than this.props.users.users.

---

Another thing that you could look at is how data is being pulled from the API and stored into the redux `store`.
If your API is giving you nested data (*one* route on an API I was using, oddly did this).

In that case..
In order to have your props/state/store object in the expected format, change this line:

```
return { ...state, users: action.payload.data };
```

to this:

```
return { ...state, users: action.payload.data.users };
```

The full function will look like this:

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
     case FETCH_USERS:
         console.log(action.payload.data)
         return { ...state, users: action.payload.data.users };
       }
  return state;
}
```